Real forms of a solvable Lie algebra
Consider the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{r}_2=\mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{C})$ of the group of affine maps of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{r}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{r}_2$.
I am interested in knowing the number of real forms that $\mathfrak{g}$ has.
Obviously, $\mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R}) \oplus \mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R})$ is a real form; actually I have found two such real forms, and I'd like to prove that there are no more.
Recall that $\mathfrak{r}_2$ is spanned by two elements $e_1, e_2$ such that $[e_1,e_2]=e_2$. As a matrix algebra, $e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\
0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $e_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\
1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$.
Hence $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{r}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{r}_2$ is given by four vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ whose non-zero brackets are:
$$
[e_1,e_2]=e_2, [e_3,e_4]=e_4
$$
In order to find real forms of $\mathfrak{g}$, if I recall correctly, we have to find conjugations of $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}=\mathfrak{g}$ seen as a real Lie algebra, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$-linear automorphisms that anticommute with $J$, where $J$ refers to multiplication by $\sqrt{-1}$.
Note that $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}$ is generated by $e_1, J e_1, \dots e_4, J e_4$. Consider the conjugation $\sigma$ so that $\sigma \circ J=-J$ and $\sigma e_i=e_i$, which has as fixed locus $\langle e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\rangle_\mathbb{R} \cong \mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R}) \oplus \mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{R})$.
There is another conjugation: the composition of $\sigma$ with the reflection that interchanges factors in $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\sigma_1=\sigma \circ r$ with $r$ the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map sending $e_1$ to $e_3$ and $e_2$ to $e_4$. The fixed locus of $\sigma_1$ is
$$
\langle e_1+e_3, e_2+e_4, J (e_1-e_3), J (e_2-e_4)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}.
$$
Indeed, if we call $x=e_1+e_3$, $y=e_2+e_4$, $z=J (e_1-e_3)$, $t=J (e_2-e_4)$ we have
$$
[x,y]=y, [x,t]=t, [z,y]=t, [z,t]=-y
$$
and this is easily seen to be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{aff}(\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}=\langle e_1, Je_1, e_2, Je_2 \rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$, so this is another real form of $\mathfrak{g}$.
In conclusion: I have found two real forms of $\mathfrak{g}$ and I suspect there are no more of them, but I don't know how to prove it.
In the literature, real forms of semisimple Lie algebras are widely studied, but not so for solvable Lie algebras. Any reference or suggestion is much welcome.

This question was answered in mathoverflow, here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473948/number-of-real-forms-of-a-not-semisimple-solvable-lie-algebra/473959?noredirect=1#comment1231855_473959
